# Why is MKMapView's mapView:viewForOverlay: not called when userlocation is enabled?

Tags: ios, delegates, mapkit, mkoverlay, userlocation

I've added some MKPolygons to my MKMapView and they are displayed just fine by the MKMapView. If I now enable the userLocation for this MKMapView and the user grants permission for his location, no delegates are called and no overlays are drawn. After the next viewDidLoad the delegates work fine again and all the overlays are displayed.

So the problem only seems to appear, if the user is asked to grant permission for his location.

I hope somebody has an explanation/solution for this strange behavior, thanks.

**Update**

As I found out, it has nothing todo with the user location. Somehow the MKMapView is not calling it's delegates for drawing the overlays, but only if it's the initial view during the first app start. After that everthing works.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Simply move the setup code into its own method and call that both from `viewDidLoad` and one of the user tracking delegate methods like `mapView:didChangeUserTrackingMode:animated:` or `mapViewWillStartLocatingUser:`.

Comment: Neither `mapViewWillStartLocatingUser:` nor  `mapView:didChangeUserTrackingMode:animated:` are being called by the mapview. `mapView: didUpdateUserLocation:` does the trick but its being called continuously so I added a flag. Any ideas why the first two are not being called?

Comment: Maybe these two methods would have been called **before** the view is actually loaded. E.g.,  `willStartLocatingUser:` might not recalled, because it is already locating the user when the view is set up. Thus, there is also no user tracking mode change (explaining why the second one is not called).

Comment: I traced it down to a Bug. If my MapView is the initial view of the app and if it is the first start, the MapView isn't drawing any Overlays. If it's not the inital view of the App, it works just fine.